# How do I capture response of form.submit

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, form-submit

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SubmitForm()
        {

            form1.submit();
        }

        function ShowResponse()
        {

        }
</script>
.
.
.
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="SubmitForm();">Click</a>
</div>
```

I want to capture the html response of `form1.submit`? How do I do this? Can I register any callback function to form1.submit method?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You won't be able to do this easily with plain javascript. When you post a form, the form inputs are sent to the server and your page is refreshed - the data is handled on the server side. That is, the `submit()` function doesn't actually return anything, it just sends the form data to the server.

If you really wanted to get the response in Javascript (without the page refreshing), then you'll need to use AJAX, and when you start talking about using AJAX, you'll *need* to use a library. [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is by far the most popular, and my personal favourite. There's a great plugin for jQuery called [Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which will do exactly what it sounds like you want.

Here's how you'd use jQuery and that plugin:

```
$('#myForm')
    .ajaxForm({
        url : 'myscript.php', // or whatever
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (response) {
            alert("The server says: " + response);
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: +1 for jQuery Form plugin. It's awesome, but you've got the 'target' attribute wrong. It is not like the 'action' attribute of the form; i.e. it is not the submit destination. From the [docs](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object): **target - Identifies the element(s) in the page to be updated with the server response.**

Comment: to be fair, you don't NEED to use a library for AJAX. libraries are written using javascript, so therefore a non-library solution exists. that said, i am 100% in favor of using a library to abstract all the ridiculousness and complexity involved in making an AJAX call.

Comment: I'm posting this comment more as an FYI that the above solution works, except when it comes to File Uploads via AJAX on IE 9 and below. I've had problems submitting files via ajax on non-HTML5 IE browsers (IE 9 and below) so I must use an iframe hack.  But using the iframe hack requires the form.submit(), but you can't wait for a response to tell you if it succeeded or not.  This has left me in a quandary.

Comment: Using a library really isn't worth it here. In pure JS the code isn't much more complicated: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() xhr.open("POST", "myscript.php");
xhr.onload=function(event){
 alert("The server says: " + event.target.response);
};
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
xhr.send(formData);`

Answer (score 76):

The non-jQuery vanilla Javascript way, extracted from 12me21's comment:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/your/url/name.php"); 
xhr.onload = function(event){ 
    alert("Success, server responded with: " + event.target.response); // raw response
}; 
// or onerror, onabort
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm")); 
xhr.send(formData);
```

For `POST`'s the default content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which matches what we're sending in the above snippet.  If you want to send "other stuff" or tweak it somehow see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for some nitty gritty details.

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer! Because all other answers do exactly the same, but obfuscated by one more layer of libraries.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, since I already have a PHP file that is handling many direct XMLHttpRequest()s on my page. But in the case of a simple form with a typical <form action = "/mysite/mycode.php"> and <submit> tags, I'm not sure how to modify.. Would I substitute my javascript httprequest calls( with a callback,) as in: <form action="myhttpreq("url, etc...)? or maybe <form action="#" onsubmit="return myhttpfunction() ? Something like that? If its that easy, this should definitely be THE answer. But I'm a little confused how to set it up.

Comment: @Randy In my case I had a button within the form like this `<input type='button' onclick="submitForm(); return false;">` or you could add an event listener for 'submit' event like Marcus' answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730069/32453

Comment: This was perfect for me. I am writing a chrome addon and am trying to avoid any libraries instead handling more complex operations on the server. This was perfect for my needs Thanks!

Answer (score 68):

An Ajax alternative is to set an invisible `<iframe>` as your form's target and read the contents of that `<iframe>` in its `onload` handler. But why bother when there's Ajax?

**Note:** I just wanted to mention this alternative since some of the answers claim that it's **impossible** to achieve this without Ajax.

Comment: Say if you wanted to post to a URL for a download through a button click?  Now you can't use Ajax for your request.  Want to then clean up or update the interface when the download is complete? Now is a time to want a callback from a POST that *isn't* Ajax.  (Necropost, I know.)

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Yup, that's still a legitimate use case for `<iframe>` POSTs (with callback to `parent`). For downloads and uploads alike...

Comment: Also as far as I know for anyone that needs compatibility with older versions of IE (7+), I'm pretty sure the iframe method is the only way to go. Please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm currently having this issue right now.

Comment: For detecting the success of a download, a neat trick I learned recently is to set a cookie in the download response and poll for the existence of that cookie in the browser.

Comment: three words: asynchronous file uploads

Comment: Note that this will only work if the form submission action is on the same site as the iframe. Otherwise Same-Origin policy will block it.

Comment: Wow, THAT was a great hack! Solved for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 61):

Future internet searchers:

For new browsers (as of 2018: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge, and most mobile browsers, but not IE), **`fetch` is a standard API that simplifies asynchronous network calls** (for which we used to need `XMLHttpRequest` or jQuery's `$.ajax`).

Here is a traditional form:

```
<form id="myFormId" action="/api/process/form" method="post">
    <!-- form fields here -->
    <button type="submit">SubmitAction</button>
</form>
```

If a form like the above is handed to you (or you created it because it is semantic html), then you can wrap the `fetch` code in an event listener as below:

```
document.forms['myFormId'].addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // TODO do something here to show user that form is being submitted
    fetch(event.target.action, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(event.target)) // event.target is the form
    }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json(); // or response.text() or whatever the server sends
    }).then((body) => {
        // TODO handle body
    }).catch((error) => {
        // TODO handle error
    });
});
```

(Or, if like the original poster you want to call it manually without a submit event, just put the `fetch` code there and pass a reference to the `form` element instead of using `event.target`.)

Docs:

Fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Other:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript
That page in 2018 does not mention fetch (yet).
But it mentions that the target="myIFrame" trick is deprecated.
And it also has an example of form.addEventListener for the 'submit' event.

Comment: Important note from MDN : 

"The Promise returned from fetch() **won’t reject on HTTP error status** even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and **it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing**."

That means then `then` callbacks must check HTTP status.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisF, I edited my answer to include a check for http status based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Answer (score 37):

I am doing it this way and its working.

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#form').attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data : $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(){
        console.log('form submitted.');
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You may want to `event.preventDefault();` (`event` = first argument of submit function) instead of `return false`. Returning false will not simply stop the browser from submitting the form but also stop other side-effects from happening that could be important. [There](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927706/761771) are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18971284/761771) of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/855605/761771) related [to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11184286/761771) this.

Comment: well, yes, return false or preventDefault or stopPropogation based on the needs.

Comment: You may need to use `FormData($("myform")[0])` if you are attempting an input type=file upload.

Comment: To be a bit more generic, you can use `event.target.action` and `$(event.target).serialize()` instead of `$('#form').attr('action')` and `$('#form').serialize()`.

Comment: Cleanest solution by far.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure that you understand what submit() does...

When you do `form1.submit();` the form information is sent to the webserver.

The WebServer will do whatever its supposed to do and return a brand new webpage to the client(usually the same page with something changed).

So, there is no way you can "catch" the return of a form.submit() action.

Comment: I created another html page and returned this as response.

Comment: how you did this approach @Khushboo

Answer (score 6):

There is no callback. It's like following a link.

If you want to capture the server response, use AJAX or post it to an Iframe and grab what appears there after the iframe's `onload()` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler for your submit button to ensure that the HTML form default `submit` event doesn't fire (which is what leads to the page refreshing).

Another alternative would be to use hackier form markup: It's the use of `<form>` and `type="submit"` that is getting in the way of the desired behavior here; as these ultimately lead to click events refreshing the page.

If you want to still use `<form>`, and you don't want to write custom click handlers, you can use jQuery's `ajax` method, which abstracts the entire problem away for you by exposing promise methods for `success`, `error`, etc.

---

To recap, you can solve your problem by either:

• preventing default behavior in the handling function by using `event.preventDefault()`

• using elements that don't have default behavior (e.g. `<form>`)

• using jQuery `ajax`

---

(i just noticed this question is from 2008, not sure why it showed up in my feed; at any rate, hopefully this is a clear answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/users/login/",    //give your url here
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: logindata,
        success: function ( data ){
        //  alert(data);    do your stuff
        },
        error: function ( data ){
        //  alert(data);    do your stuff
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my code for this problem:

```html
<form id="formoid" action="./demoText.php" title="" method="post">
    <div>
        <label class="title">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {
        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
        var $form = $(this), url = $form.attr('action');

        /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            name: $('#name').val()
        });

        /* Alerts the results */
        posting.done(function(data) {
            alert('success');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to capture the output of an AJAX request using Chrome you can follow these simple steps:

1. Open up the Programmers toolbox
2. Go to the console and right anywhere inside it
3. In the menu that appears, click "Enable XMXHTTPRequest Logging"
4. After doing that everytime you make an AJAX request a message starting with "XHR finished loading:http://......" will appear in your console.
5. Clicking on the link that appears, will bring the "Resources tab" where your can see the headers and the content of the response!

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by @rajesh_kw (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567796/4946681), I handle form post errors and success:

```
    $('#formName').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // or return false, your choice
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // if success, HTML response is expected, so replace current
                if(textStatus === 'success') {
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236378/4946681
                    var newDoc = document.open('text/html', 'replace');
                    newDoc.write(data);
                    newDoc.close();
                }
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(jqXHR.status == 0 || jqXHR == 302) {
                alert('Your session has ended due to inactivity after 10 minutes.\nPlease refresh this page, or close this window and log back in to system.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown error returned while saving' + (typeof errorThrown == 'string' && errorThrown.trim().length > 0 ? ':\n' + errorThrown : ''));
            }
        });
    });
```

I make use of `this` so that my logic is reusable, I expect HTML to be returned on a success so I render it and replace the current page, and in my case I expect a redirect to the login page if the session is timed out, so I intercept that redirect in order to preserve the state of the page.

Now users can log in via another tab and try their submit again.

Answer (score 1):

I have Following code perfactly run using ajax with multi-part form data

```
function getUserDetail()
{
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    var gender =$("#userForm input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    //var gender2 = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
    //alert("fn"+firstName+lastName+username+email);
    var roleIndex = document.getElementById("role");
    var role = roleIndex.options[roleIndex.selectedIndex].value;
    var jobTitleIndex = document.getElementById("jobTitle");
    var jobTitle = jobTitleIndex.options[jobTitleIndex.selectedIndex].value;
    var shiftIdIndex = document.getElementById("shiftId");
    var shiftId = shiftIdIndex.options[shiftIdIndex.selectedIndex].value;


    var addressLine1 = document.getElementById("addressLine1").value;
    var addressLine2 = document.getElementById("addressLine2").value;
    var streetRoad = document.getElementById("streetRoad").value;

    var countryIndex = document.getElementById("country");
    var country = countryIndex.options[countryIndex.selectedIndex].value;

    var stateIndex = document.getElementById("state");
    var state = stateIndex.options[stateIndex.selectedIndex].value;

    var cityIndex = document.getElementById("city");
    var city = cityIndex.options[cityIndex.selectedIndex].value;



    var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;

    var branchIndex = document.getElementById("branch");
    var branch = branchIndex.options[branchIndex.selectedIndex].value;

    var language = document.getElementById("language").value;
    var profilePicture = document.getElementById("profilePicture").value;
    //alert(profilePicture);
    var addDocument = document.getElementById("addDocument").value;


    var shiftIdIndex = document.getElementById("shiftId");
    var shiftId = shiftIdIndex.options[shiftIdIndex.selectedIndex].value;


    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('firstName', firstName);
    data.append('lastName', lastName);
    data.append('username', username);
    data.append('email', email);
    data.append('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
    data.append('role', role);
    data.append('jobTitle', jobTitle);
    data.append('gender', gender);
    data.append('shiftId', shiftId);
    data.append('lastName', lastName);
    data.append('addressLine1', addressLine1);
    data.append('addressLine2', addressLine2);
    data.append('streetRoad', streetRoad);
    data.append('country', country);
    data.append('state', state);
    data.append('city', city);
    data.append('pincode', pincode);
    data.append('branch', branch);
    data.append('language', language);
    data.append('profilePicture', $('#profilePicture')[0].files[0]);
     for (var i = 0; i < $('#document')[0].files.length; i++) {
            data.append('document[]', $('#document')[0].files[i]);
        }



    $.ajax({
        //url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/save-user',
        type: "POST",
        Accept: "application/json",
        async: true,
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        cache: false,

        success : function(data) {      
            reset();
            $(".alert alert-success alert-div").text("New User Created Successfully!");
         },
       error :function(data, textStatus, xhr){
           $(".alert alert-danger alert-div").text("new User Not Create!");
        }


    });


//

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using AJAX. Submitting the form usually results in the browser loading a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using javascript and AJAX technology. Have a look at jquery and at this [form plug in](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). You only need to include two js files to register a callback for the form.submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitform() {
      $.ajax({
        headers: { 
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        type: "POST",
        url : "/hello.hello",
        dataType : "json",
        data : JSON.stringify({"hello_name": "hello"}),
        error: function () {
          alert('loading Ajax failure');
        },
     onFailure: function () {
          alert('Ajax Failure');
     },
     statusCode: {
          404: function() {
          alert("missing info");
          }   
     },
        success : function (response) {
          alert("The server says: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
      })
      .done(function( data ) {
        $("#result").text(data['hello']);
      });
};</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : "<wiki:action path='/your struts action'/>",//path of url where u want to submit form
            type : "POST",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                var treeMenuFrame = parent.frames['wikiMenu'];
                if (treeMenuFrame) {
                    treeMenuFrame.location.href = treeMenuFrame.location.href;
                }
                var contentFrame = parent.frames['wikiContent'];
                contentFrame.document.open();
                contentFrame.document.write(data);
                contentFrame.document.close();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

First of all use `$(document).ready(function())` inside this use `('formid').submit(function(event))` and then prevent default action after that call ajax form submission `$.ajax({, , , , });`

It will take  parameter u can choose according your requirement
then call a function

```
success:function(data) {
    // do whatever you want my example to put response html on div 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we will need serializeObject();

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

then you make a basic post and get response

```
$.post("/Education/StudentSave", $("#frmNewStudent").serializeObject(), function (data) {
if(data){
//do true 
}
else
{
//do false
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and return nicely structured JSON answers from server. It also allows you to validate/sanitize your data directly on server, which is a good practice because it's more secure (and even easier) than doing this on client.

For example if you need to post html form to server (to saveprofilechanges.php) with user data for simple registration:

I. Client parts:

I.a. HTML part:

```
<form id="user_profile_form">
  <label for="first_name"><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required />First name</label>
  <label for="family_name"><input type="text" name="family_name" id="family_name" required />Family name</label>
  <label for="email"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />Email</label> 
  <input type="submit" value="Save changes" id="submit" />
</form>
```

I.b. Script part:

```
$(function () {
    $("#user_profile_form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var postData = {
        first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
        family_name: $('#family_name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
      };
      $.post("/saveprofilechanges.php", postData,
        function(data) {
          var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          if (json.ExceptionMessage != undefined) {
            alert(json.ExceptionMessage); // the exception from the server
            $('#' + json.Field).focus(); // focus the specific field to fill in
          }
          if (json.SuccessMessage != undefined) {
            alert(json.SuccessMessage); // the success message from server
          }
       });
    });
});
```

II. Server part (saveprofilechanges.php):

```
$data = $_POST;
if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
    // Some data validation:
    if (empty($data['first_name']) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $data['first_name'])) {
       echo json_encode(array(
         'ExceptionMessage' => "First name missing or incorrect (only letters and spaces allowed).",
         'Field' => 'first_name' // Form field to focus in client form
       ));
       return FALSE;
    }
    if (empty($data['family_name']) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $data['family_name'])) {
       echo json_encode(array(
         'ExceptionMessage' => "Family name missing or incorrect (only letters and spaces allowed).",
         'Field' => 'family_name' // Form field to focus in client form
       ));
       return FALSE;
    }
    if (empty($data['email']) || !filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       echo json_encode(array(
         'ExceptionMessage' => "Email missing or incorrectly formatted. Please enter it again.",
         'Field' => 'email' // Form field to focus in client form
       ));
       return FALSE;
    }
    // more actions..
    // more actions..
    try {
       // Some save to database or other action..:
       $this->User->update($data, array('username=?' => $username));
       echo json_encode(array(
         'SuccessMessage' => "Data saved!"
       ));
       return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo json_encode(array(
         'ExceptionMessage' => $e->getMessage()
       ));
       return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

you can do that without ajax.

write your  like below.

..
..
..

and then in "action.php"

then after frmLogin.submit();

read variable $submit_return..

$submit_return contains return value.

good luck.