# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

i am getting this error when the below condition match, i am using the below code in Content page and in my master page i have this

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" ID="smgr" runat="server" />
```

**Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected**

```
 if (lstRecipient.Items[i].Text == ddlRecipient.SelectedItem.Text)
 {
   lstRecipient.Items.RemoveAt(i);
   isDuplicate = true;
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertAdd", "jAlert('Recipient name is already in the list.', 'Duplicate Entry!');", true);
 }
```

Comment: if you have JavaScript function on your page, put Return False, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically caused when a jscript function cannot be resolved. Do you have a reference to the JQuery library containing the jAlert function?

Comment: i have that in my Master page.

Comment: @Nisar Khan - Can you confirm that the library is getting loaded using a tool like Firebug? Path is correct? What happens if you change the code to a Javascript alert instead? Does it now work? What does the script block that is being generated look like? A few ideas of things to try.

Comment: my scripts were in  "<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">" and i moved those scripts to <head> section now its working.