# Slidedown div not appearing on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user chooses their options form the form the user clicks submit, I then want to output the values in a div, but the div is initially hidden and slidesdown upon submit if it meets certain criteria. Below is my code so you can see my set up and what I have tried.

I have a form:

```
<form id="toBeTranslatedForm" action="fun-translator.php" method="POST" >
      <textarea id="toBeTranslatedTextArea"></textarea>
      <select id="translationOptions"></select>
      <input type="submit" value="Translate" />
</form>
```

I have a div below that form:

```
<div id="translatedArea">
       <h2>Translated Text</h2>
       <div id="translatedText"></div>
</div>
```

My javascript is:

```
var __submitted = false;

function populateTranslationOptions() {
    var translationOptions = ["Egyptian Hieroglyphs",
                             "Al Bhed (Final Fantasy X)", 
                             "Futurama"];

    $.each(translationOptions, function(index, value) {
        $("#translationOptions")
            .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value)
                    .text(value));
    });
}

function getFormValues()
{
    $('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
        __submitted = true;
        var textAreaValue = $('#toBeTranslatedTextArea').val();
        var selectValue = $('#translationOptions').val();
        outputTranslated();
    });
}

function outputTranslated()
{
    $('#translatedArea').slideDown();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    populateTranslationOptions();
    getFormValues();
    //outputTranslated();
});
```

The css for the div thats meant to be shown on submit is:

```
#translatedArea
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Does `return false;` after `$('#translatedArea').slideDown();` helps ?

Comment: Then, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you plan to handle the translation part, but just adding 
    `return false;`
to the end of:

```
    function getFormValues()
    {
         $('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
        __submitted = true;
        var textAreaValue = $('#toBeTranslatedTextArea').val();
        var selectValue = $('#translationOptions').val();
       outputTranslated();
        return false;
    });
 }
```

seems to work - I put it in jsfiddle and that's the only modification I made. I noticed that the `translatedArea` was sliding down already but then the page was going to a 404 before you could see it work.

Comment: this worked for me. thank you. but what does return false do, why did this work.

Comment: Hi! Glad it worked. To find out a more about why `return false;`, see this SO question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript). Basically your original script seemed not to work because the form, when submitted, tried to open up a new page `fun-translator.php`, which is specified by the `<form>` tag. By using `return false;` we are basically preventing this behaviour. Hope that helps!