# window.location only working with alert after ut

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm validating a form and after validation, I want to redirect with window.location = xxx but it doesn't work unless I put an alert call after it.

The validation works by handling the onsubmit event of the form.

```
function isvalid()
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('txtTitle');
        if (txt.value == '')
        {   alert('Please enter a title'); return false;}
        else 
        {

            var sURL = "get_movies.php?title=" + txt
            window.location.href = sURL;
            //alert('');
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but months ago I notice that _some_ browsers only support `document.location`. But `location.assign()` (without any prefix object) always work. You may want to try that.

Comment: after the onsubmit is handled did you return false to stop the event bubbling?

Comment: try to use `return false` instead of `returns true`

Comment: @andrean I used return false and it worked. I also changed the redirect code to document.location

Comment: @NareshJ thanks, return false works, but can you explain why?

Comment: @user1477707, I explained why it works in my answer (and sorry for the confusion around the typo in the last sentence, it's fixed now)

Comment: @user1477707, just for your information, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form's `onsubmit` expects either a true or false return value.  If you return true, the form will be submitted.  Since you want to manually set the `window.location` on a form submit, it doesn't make sense to return true (you will then have the page fighting over a form submit and a JS redirect.

Put `return false` in your else block and you should be good to go.

Comment: I understand our logic but did you mean "Put return false"? typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.location = sUrl;
```

It always works for me.