# Displat form after clicking button

Tags: javascript, forms, button, dom-events

I have a question to you about JavaScript.  I want to display form after clicking a button and then when I write something and click submit it must display the value of form on screen. And the problem is that when I click submit it display only for a second. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var dod = document.getElementById("dodaj")
    dod.onclick = function () {
        document.write("<form action='?' id='formualrz'><input id='f1' type='text' name='pole' value='Nazwa'><input id='f2' type='text' name='pole' value='Opis'><input type='submit' id='sub'></form>");
        var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
        var f2 = document.getElementById("f2");
        var submit = document.getElementById("sub");

        submit.onclick = function () {
            document.write(f1.value + "<br/>" + f2.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's submitting the form when you click the submit button, which is why you only see the results for a short amount of time. Plenty of information already available on how to prevent form submission when clicking the submit button.

Comment: It was created by the javascript men upon loading.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is being submitted. Add the following to your `form` tag

```
<form onsubmit="return(false)" >
```

Or in your case on the event handler:

```
submit.onclick = function () {
     document.write(f1.value + "<br/>" + f2.value);
     return(false);
}
```

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript) explains what `return false` actually does.