# Page is getting refreshed in web form .aspx file while clicking on button?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have created a webform file with login.aspx. But when i am clicking on the button the page is getting refreshed and the javascript function is getting called instead what i want is that after clicking on the button the page should not get refreshed and should be able to invoke the javascript function?

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <form runat="server">
  <button id="formsubmission" onclick="myfunction()"> GetData </button>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `event.preventDefault()` to stop default behaviour in `myfunction()`.

so your function will look like:

```
function myfunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set return false after the function call.Otherwise page gets full postback.

```
<button id="Button1" onclick="myfunction(); return false;"> GetData </button>
```

`Return false` prevents from page postbacks after executing the function..

You can refer the link below for reading more about **return false**

[Return false in javascript..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need page *refresh* simply return `false` after function call and make sure you do not get any error in function call.

```
<button id="formsubmission" onclick="myfunction(); return false;"> GetData </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preventDefault for this.

```
$("#formsubmission").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // code to execute
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<button>` tag , it will act as a submit button, it will post back. So use `type="button"` in `<button>` tag , it will not allow to post back , it will act like html control.

Try this:

```
<button type="button" id="formsubmission" onclick="myfunction()"> GetData </button>
```