# jQuery form submit as per referenced form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is one form example. It is working good without any issue.

```
    <form action="http://example.com/add_to_cart" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
    <button type="submit" value="submit"> Add to Cart</button>

<form action="http://example.com/add_to_cart" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
<button type="submit" value="submit"> Add to Cart</button>

<form action="http://example.com/add_to_cart" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
<button type="submit" value="submit"> Add to Cart</button>
```

Now I have to create the same form but a little modification needed. I have my markup like this

```
    <form action="http://example.com/add_to_cart" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" data-value="10" data-name="id">Try Now</button>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" data-value="3" data-name="id">Try Now</button>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" data-value="5" data-name="id">Try Now</button>
 </form>   
To submit the form I have used this jQuery. 


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('button[type=submit]').click(function() {
        var Id = jQuery(this).attr('data-value');
        var Name = jQuery(this).attr('data-name');
        alert(Name);
      })
    });
  </script>
```

But from this point of jQuery I don't know what to do next. So can someone kindly tell me how to submit the form by jquery with the same values as used above markup?

**Update**
Yes I can change my markup if you think so.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML is not correct. Move the inputs **inside** of the form:

```
<form action="..." class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
    <button type="submit" value="submit"> Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

You can have any number of forms like above. In the JavaScript side you have to catch `submit` event for all forms. In the submit handler, `this` will be the form that was submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").on("submit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: formUrl,
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function (data) {
                /* handle success */
            },
            error: function (data) {
                /* handle error */
            },
            dataType: "json" // remove this if the server doesn't send json data
        });
        return false; // prevent default browser behavior 
    });
});
```

Note `$(this).serializeArray()` - this returns an array like this:

```
[{
  name: "some-input-name",
  value: "some-input-value"
}, ...
```

Also, you may checkout the `return false` usage: [When and why to 'return false' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855360/1420197)