# Why does onclick event cause a turn page event in ibook ebook reader?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, epub, ibooks

I am writing an ebook for the apple ibooks app.  I am making it an interactive ebook through the use of javascript.  I have the javascript working in a browser.  And to some degree it works in the apple ibooks app.  When I use the onclick event, the function is executed both in the browser and in ibooks.  However, in ibooks, it also initiates a page turn event.  The onclick event is not seen unless one goes back to the previous page.  My javascript is as follows.

```
      //<![CDATA[
    function changekey(direction){
      //all 12 major keys
      var  keyArray = ["C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab","A","Bb","B"];
      //12 notes of each major key including non major scale notes
      var  keyNotes = {C:"C,C#/Db,D,D#/Eb,E,F,F#/Gb,G,G#/Ab,A,A#/Bb,B,C",
                       Db:"Db,D,Eb,E,F,Gb,G,Ab,A,Bb,B,C,Db",
                       D:"D,D#/Db,E,F,F#,G,G#/Ab,A,A#/Bb,B,C,C#,D",
                       Eb:"Eb,F,F#/Gb,G,Ab,A,Bb,B,C,C#/Db,E,Eb",
                       E:"E,F,F#,G,G#,A,A#/Bb,B,C,C#,D,D#,E",
                       F:"F,F#/Gb,G,G#/Ab,A,Bb,B,C,C#/Db,D,D#/Eb,E,F",
                       Gb:"Gb,G,Ab,A,Bb,Cb,C,Db,D,Eb,E,F,Gb",
                       G:"G,G#/Ab,A,A#/Bb,B,C,C#/Db,D,D#/Eb,E,F,F#,G",
                       Ab:"Ab,A,Bb,B,C,Db,D,Eb,E,F,F#/Gb,G,Ab",
                       A:"A,A#/Bb,B,C,C#,D,D#/Eb,E,F,F#,G,G#,A",
                       Bb:"Bb,B,C,C#/Db,D,Eb,E,F,F#/Gb,G,G#/Ab,A,Bb",
                       B:"B,C,C#,D,D#,E,F,F#,G,G#,A,A#,B"
                       };
      var currentKey = document.getElementById("MajorScale").innerHTML;
      var newNotes = [];
      var newKey;
      var firstChar;
      var secondChar = [];
      var secondCharText = [];

      if(direction == "down"){
        if(keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)==0){
          document.getElementById("MajorScale").innerHTML=keyArray[keyArray.length-1];
          newKey=keyArray[keyArray.length-1];
        } else{
          document.getElementById("MajorScale").innerHTML=keyArray[keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)-1];
          newKey=keyArray[keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)-1];
        }
      } else if( direction == "up") {
        if(keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)==keyArray.length-1){
          document.getElementById("MajorScale").innerHTML=keyArray[0];
          newKey = keyArray[0];
        } else {
          document.getElementById("MajorScale").innerHTML=keyArray[keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)+1];
          newKey = keyArray[keyArray.indexOf(currentKey)+1];
        }
      }

      newNotes = (keyNotes[newKey]).split(",");

      for (var nn=0;nn < newNotes.length;nn++){
        while (document.getElementById("Note"+(nn+1)).firstChild) {
          document.getElementById("Note"+(nn+1)).removeChild(document.getElementById("Note"+(nn+1)).firstChild);
        }
        firstChar = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
        firstChar.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","Utsaah");
        firstChar.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size",25);
        var firstCharText = document.createTextNode(newNotes[nn][0]);
        firstChar.appendChild(firstCharText);
        document.getElementById("Note"+(nn+1)).appendChild(firstChar);

        for(i=1;i<newNotes[nn].length;i++){
          secondChar[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
          if(i==1||i==4){
            secondChar[i].setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","OpusText");
          } else {
            secondChar[i].setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","Utsaah");
          }
          secondChar[i].setAttributeNS(null,"font-size",25);
          secondCharText[i] = document.createTextNode(newNotes[nn][i]);
          secondChar[i].appendChild(secondCharText[i]);
          document.getElementById("Note"+(nn+1)).appendChild(secondChar[i]);
        }

      }
    }
  //]]>
```

It modifies the following svg files.

```
<div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="660px"
 height="105px" viewBox="0 0 660 105" enable-background="new 0 0 660 105" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="Layer_1">
<g id="TwelveTones">
    <text id="Note1" style="text-anchor: middle" x="030" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">G</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note2" style="text-anchor: middle" x="080" y="50" fill="#A7A9AB"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">G</tspan><tspan font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">/A</tspan><tspan x="39.835" y="0" fill="#A7A9AB" font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">b</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note3" style="text-anchor: middle" x="130" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">A</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note4" style="text-anchor: middle" x="180" y="50" fill="#A7A9AB"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">A</tspan><tspan font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">/B</tspan><tspan x="37.845" y="0" fill="#A7A9AB" font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">b</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note5" style="text-anchor: middle" x="230" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">B</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note6" style="text-anchor: middle" x="280" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">C</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note7" style="text-anchor: middle" x="330" y="50" fill="#A7A9AB"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">C</tspan><tspan font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">/D</tspan><tspan x="39.822" y="0" fill="#A7A9AB" font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">b</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note8" style="text-anchor: middle" x="380" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">D</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note9" style="text-anchor: middle" x="430" y="50" fill="#A7A9AB"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">D</tspan><tspan font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">/E</tspan><tspan x="38.833" y="0" fill="#A7A9AB" font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">b</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note10" style="text-anchor: middle" x="480" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">E</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note11" style="text-anchor: middle" x="530" y="50" fill="#A7A9AB"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">F</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note12" style="text-anchor: middle" x="580" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">F</tspan><tspan font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan></text>
    <text id="Note13" style="text-anchor: middle" x="630" y="50"><tspan font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">G</tspan></text>
</g>
<g id="Aarows">
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M233.75,35.844
                c11.329-23.826,31.709-24.192,40.741-3.947"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M274.244,31.39c0.835-1.893,3.28-3.589,5.131-4.368c-1.787,2.844-3.036,6.124-3.125,9.541
                    c-2.317-2.484-5.541-3.906-8.74-4.94C269.576,31.006,272.198,30.553,274.244,31.39z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M583.75,35.844
                c11.329-23.826,31.709-24.192,40.741-3.947"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M624.244,31.39c0.835-1.893,3.28-3.589,5.131-4.368c-1.787,2.844-3.036,6.124-3.125,9.541
                    c-2.317-2.484-5.541-3.906-8.74-4.94C619.576,31.006,622.198,30.553,624.244,31.39z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M37.5,54.002
                c18.481,19.995,57.959,24.049,81.452,3"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M118.521,57.361c-2.069-0.029-4.585-1.618-6.025-3.017c3.316,0.534,6.824,0.403,10.003-0.85
                    c-1.382,3.103-1.431,6.627-1.134,9.975C119.992,61.808,118.55,59.571,118.521,57.361z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M137.5,54.002
                c18.481,19.995,57.959,24.049,81.452,3"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M218.522,57.361c-2.069-0.029-4.585-1.618-6.025-3.017c3.316,0.534,6.824,0.403,10.003-0.85
                    c-1.382,3.103-1.431,6.627-1.134,9.975C219.992,61.808,218.55,59.571,218.522,57.361z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M287.5,54.002
                c18.481,19.995,57.959,24.049,81.452,3"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M368.522,57.361c-2.069-0.029-4.585-1.618-6.025-3.017c3.316,0.534,6.824,0.403,10.003-0.85
                    c-1.382,3.103-1.431,6.627-1.134,9.975C369.992,61.808,368.55,59.571,368.522,57.361z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M387.5,54.002
                c18.481,19.995,57.959,24.049,81.452,3"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M468.522,57.361c-2.069-0.029-4.585-1.618-6.025-3.017c3.316,0.534,6.824,0.403,10.003-0.85
                    c-1.382,3.103-1.431,6.627-1.134,9.975C469.992,61.808,468.55,59.571,468.522,57.361z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#AA1800" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M487.5,54.002
                c18.481,19.995,57.959,24.049,81.452,3"/>
            <g>
                <path fill="#AA1800" d="M568.522,57.361c-2.069-0.029-4.585-1.618-6.025-3.017c3.316,0.534,6.824,0.403,10.003-0.85
                    c-1.382,3.103-1.431,6.627-1.134,9.975C569.992,61.808,568.55,59.571,568.522,57.361z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</g>
<g id="Steps">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 71.5527 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">W</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 171.5529 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">W</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 598.5363 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">H</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 248.5363 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">H</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 321.5525 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">W</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 421.5523 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">W</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 521.5523 90.5519)" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="25">W</text>
</g>
</svg></p><p>
<svg onclick='changekey("down");' version="1.1" id="downkey" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 20.641 22.713" enable-background="new 0 0 20.641 22.713" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon fill="#44612B" points="18.27,1.532 1,11.505 18.27,21.478"  />
</svg> <span id="MajorScale" display="inline-block" width="150">G</span> Major Scale
<svg version="1.1" onclick='changekey("up");' id="upkey" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 20.641 22.713" enable-background="new 0 0 20.641 22.713" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon fill="#324DCE" points="1.913,21.478 19.183,11.505 1.913,1.532"  />
</svg></p>
    </div>
```

I have tried changing the `onclick='changekey("down");'` to an ontouchstart and ontouchend event, but those were not recognized within the ibooks app.

The working browser code can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/9772W/1/
And a sample ebook for ibooks can be seen here. The interactive portion is on page 3 and it changes the pages to page 4 or page 2 depending upon which button is tapped. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x1uex3cbw56c7k/Example.epub

I'm trying to find what is triggering the page turn event and how to disable it for that function.

Thanks,
 --christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `onclick` event is also getting passed up to the iBooks application, so it triggers both your code, as well as the default code that handles `onclick`. If you add `return false;` to the end of your Javascript function, it should fix it.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript) explains it a bit more.

Comment: It did not work at the last line of my javascript, but did work great when I put it in the function call in the html onclick.  Basically like this `onclick='changekey("down");return false;'`

Comment: Oh, that works. The other way to fix it would be to add return as the last line, and then do `onclick='return changekey("down")'`