# My function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Upon clicking the search button, the function is suppose to attach the search input to the Google URL. However, it seems as though the function neglects the variable because it redirects to Google's homepage although something was typed in the search bar.

```js
document.getElementById('searchbtn').onclick = searchExplore;
function searchExplore () {
 var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;   
 document.getElementById('searchform').action = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+input;
}
```

```css
body{
}
.search{
  text-align:center;
  background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding:20px;
  }
form{
  display:inline-flex;
}
#searchbar{
  font-size:35px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 0 0 20px;
  border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  }
#searchbtn{
  font-size:35px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 90px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#searchbar:hover,#searchbar:focus{
  box-shadow:-3px 3px 15px;
}
#searchbtn:hover,#searchbtn:focus{
  box-shadow:-.1px 3px 15px 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mypen1.css" type="text/css"/>
  <title>MJ Search</title>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="search">
    <form id="searchform" action="">
         <input id="searchbar" type= "search" placeholder="Search & Explore..."/>
         <button id="searchbtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mypen1.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Just by doing your way I think that first you need to `preventDefault()` (the initial submit), then attach `action` url, then manually `submit`

Comment: but anyways you need a way to view that query result somewhere; how you do that?

Answer (score 0):

HTML file:

```
<form id="searchform" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return searchExplore()">
     <input id="searchbar" type= "search" placeholder="Search & Explore..."/>
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS File:

```
function searchExplore () {
    var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+input;
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why is false returned, just curious?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript

Was my earlier answer useful? Create an html file with this little code, and check whether it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Why is false returned?

Comment: You didn't bother to click on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript) above, did you?

Comment: I did, but check out my last comment on the 2nd post.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use form, then you need to call `event.preventDefault()` as first statement in the function, (also you need to modify function definition to -->searchExplore(event))

Otherwise, remove the form from html, and simply use `document.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+input;` inside the searchExplore function, and you need not use `event.preventDefault()` as well

Comment: What exactly does event.preventDefault( ) do in this situation?

Comment: I tried your method. It doesn’t search at all now. I still what the search button to work, but, for example if I search “cat”, I want it to go to the link “http://www.google.com/search?q=cat” instead of “http://www.google.com/search?q=“.

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, please ping me

Comment: what's the issue ping can you share

Comment: my skypeId : learnakshayjain, you can share screen if you wish

Comment: it wont take more than 5 minutes, if you have hangout we can connect there as well, my gmail is theakshay.jain@gmail.com