# Script not working on first click only on second

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I'm new to js and I have this problem

---

I want on click to change a height of one element to width of another element
and this code works properly by for some reason I have to click twice, any suggestions how to make it to work on first click?

```
<script>
var l = document.getElementById("tablinks");

l.onclick = function(){

var w = document.getElementById("img1").offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("beforeafter1").style.height = w + "px";

};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below script.

```
<script>
//var l = document.getElementById("tablinks");
function doMyTrick(){
    var w = document.getElementById("img1").offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById("beforeafter1").style.height = w + "px";

};
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:doMyTrick()" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: It worked well in one click since it's a simple script. I already tested that script in Chrome browser. Try with some different browsers to verify.

Answer (score -1):

The link/button code is missing, but I guess you didn't put `return false;` to your javascript code:

```
<a href='#' id="tablinks" onclick='someFunc(3.1415926); return false;'>Click here !</a>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legit answer according to stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/855376/3520059