# matTooltip not working correctly on iOS (Safari)

Tags: ios, angular, angular-material, tooltip, angular-material2

I'm using the `Tooltip` from `Angular Material` and the tooltip doesn't display correctly on iOS (Safari). This is the behavior I experience:

- iPhone with iOS 12: long tap on the button shows the tooltip, but also executes the `click` event
- iPad with iOS 13: no tooltip at all on long tap
- iPhone with iOS 14: tooltip is shown on long tap, but the popup menu (cut, copy, paste, ...) appears and a text below is selected

On Android everything is working as expected. Seems to me that the `matTooltip` is not really working on iOS at all. This is my setup:

Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Angular: 8.2.14
@angular/cdk 8.2.3
@angular/material 8.2.3

My sample code is based on [this here](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview):

**app.component.html**

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
        (click)="clickEvent()">
  Action
</button>
```

**app.component.css:**

```css
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tooltip';

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  clickEvent(){
    window.alert('clicked');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried to apply special CSS (see above), but that CSS must be applied in the different way to take effect. But still there are problems with elements, which are not selectable (e.g. in a form).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

[Angular material docs on tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) (see the api section -> Directives -> MatToolTip -> properties -> TouchGestures), actually specifies a bit on this behavior:

How touch gestures should be handled by the tooltip. On touch devices the tooltip directive uses a long press gesture to show and hide, however it can conflict with the native browser gestures. To work around the conflict, Angular Material disables native gestures on the trigger, but that might not be desirable on particular elements (e.g. inputs and draggable elements). The different values for this option configure the touch event handling as follows:

- auto - Enables touch gestures for all elements, but tries to avoid
  conflicts with native browser gestures on particular elements. In
  particular, it allows text selection on inputs and textareas, and
  preserves the native browser dragging on elements marked as
  draggable.
- on - Enables touch gestures for all elements and disables
  native browser gestures with no exceptions.
- off - Disables touch
  gestures. Note that this will prevent the tooltip from showing on
  touch devices.

Based on this, something like this could be tried with your sample code:

```
<button mat-raised-button #tooltip="matTooltip"
        matTooltip='Info about&#13;the action'
        matTooltipPosition="right"
        matTooltipClass="allow-cr"
        aria-tooltip="Button that displays and hides a tooltip triggered by other buttons"
        matTooltipTouchGestures="on">
  Action
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Tomorrow I'll test more (because my iOS 14 device is currently not available). I tried it with the other devices with the following result: With the click event, everything stays the same. Without the click event it does work on the iOS 12 device, but still not on the iPad ... Which role does `(click)` play here?

Comment: Though I could not understand your comment clearly, but you may try returning false at the end of clickEvent() function execution to prevent the default behavior. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript#:~:text=You%20use%20return%20false%20to,prevent%20the%20submit%20from%20working.&text=When%20a%20return%20statement%20is,returned%20to%20the%20function%20caller.

Comment: My current results: **iPad with iOS 13**: tooltip not working at all. **iPhone with iOS 12**: *click* event is triggered on long tap despite `return false` inside the event, but when *click* event is removed eveything is working as desired here. **iPhone Simulator with iOS 14**: long tap shows tooltip, but also selects the text (in this case the text "info"). What all have in common (except the iPad): single tap not also executes the *click* event, but also shows the tooltip (not so important, but I wanted to mention this). Is there anything I can do to improve the behavior of the tooltip?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't suggest anything specific to IOS events that are executed, my answers were based on Angular docs which is the best I could have provided based on specification in API section.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help anyway. Do you think I should report this as bug or am I doing something still wrong?