# Change content of entire page without reloading

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking for a way to change the html content of my entire page (even the head) , after an ajax call.

So I can't use :

```
$("body").html(result)
```

I have this code :

```
$.ajax({
url: myURL,
type: "POST",
success: function (result) {
   document.open();
   document.write(result);
   document.close();
}
```

But it's reloading the page. I don't want it because the transition is bad (my pages background color is black and there is a white flash during the refresh).

I need something like :

```
$("html").html(result)
```

But it doens't works. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: in your respinse only get html not any script like js script

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825586/inplace-replace-entire-html-document