# Can fetch be used to replace the entire document or html element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In a web extension, I've been passing template elements from the background page as strings to an empty local HTML file and using `browser.tabs.insertCSS` and `browser.tabs.executeScript` to pass CSS and JS. That has been working well but I recently learned that fetch can be used to retrieve the files from the extension directly, which would reduce the size of the background page or eliminate it altogether, leaving just the background script and reducing RAM usage.

I've seen some examples in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631762/returning-html-with-fetch) that write the HTML string to the body element using `innerHTML` and one that uses a `DOMParser.` But if you try it, the HTML is added to the body element.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825586/replace-entire-html-document-in-place), ten years old, had a five-year-old last response that was interesting, to a novice like me anyway; and I tried this, which appears to work.

```
fetch('file.html')
.then( response => response.text() )
.then( result => {
        let parser = new DOMParser(),
            doc = parser.parseFromString( result, 'text/html' );
        document.replaceChild( doc.documentElement, document.documentElement );
    } );
```

My question is, is this a valid and reliable method of replacing the html element completely?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens to your javascript event handlers etc.,

Comment: I can see in the inspector that the script tag came with the HTML document but the events are not working in my little test file. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I need to figure out how to make the script run or still inject it through the extension.

Comment: The script tag shows up in the inspector but the source data is still the old html and script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This will have unintended side-effects in some cases.

Here is a simple example demonstrating this:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>DOM Parser test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is the original file</h1>
  <button id="btn1" type="button">Click to reload</button>

  <script>
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
    function onClick() {
      fetch('file.html')
       .then( response => response.text() )
       .then( result => {
          let parser = new DOMParser();
          doc = parser.parseFromString( result, 'text/html' );
          document.replaceChild( doc.documentElement, document.documentElement );
        } );
    }

    btn1.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

file.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>DOM Parser test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is the second file</h1>
  <button id="btn1" type="button">Click to reload</button>

  <script>
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
    function onClick() {
      fetch('file.html')
       .then( response => response.text() )
       .then( result => {
          let parser = new DOMParser();
          doc = parser.parseFromString( result, 'text/html' );
          document.replaceChild( doc.documentElement, document.documentElement );
        } );
    }

    btn1.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html body {
      background: #00003f;
}
```

I served these static files using node JS `http-server ./` and accessed index.html

[image]

Now click the "Click to Reload" button. This should fetch file.html and render it.

[image]

As you can see in the source code of index.html and file.html, they both reference style.css stylesheet. index.html rendered the styles referenced whereas file.html which was fetched and used to update the documentElement did not honor the stylesheet.

This is one example of how things can break.

Comment: Thank you for the example. That's very interesting and saved me a lot of trouble, probably several wasted hours of thinking I was just doing something wrong within the extension. Would it be safe to use fetch to get the other DOM elements content only, that which would be provided through the template elements in the background page, and then add the CSS and JS through the browser.tab methods?

Comment: I have been using `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the template as a string because cannot pass a DOM node from the background to the page.  Perhaps those templates can be separate HTML files in the extension such that they could be fetched, parsed, and used to replace the body element or the content of the body element, after which the browser tabs methods can add the CSS and JS. This would still allow for reduction in size or removal of a background HTML page.

Comment: Yes. insertAdjacentHTML if you want to insert components that need to obey global context and the Shadow DOM if you want to use self-contained components (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time since I asked this question and I barely understood enough to ask it. Since then I've learned a little and think this is possible. I'm not claiming it is the professional way to do it or even a good idea to do it, but it has worked out well for my projects.

Please do not think that I'm writing this because I think I've discovered something new or novel. I'm writing it because, if had I known it back when I asked this question, I could've accomplished my objective more easily.

Below `rspObj.data` is the HTML document text however it is retrieved, such as by a `fetch`, the code of which is not included.

The issue was that scripts were not executed and style sheets were not applied even though they appeared in the console as if loaded. If style sheets are added to the `head`, and `script` elements added to the `body` and their attributes set, both as separate steps, then they are accepted and executed.

Previous scripts appears to remain in the list of sources in developer tools, but they don't appear to be able to be used again by the new document. That might be because I was using modules; I'm not sure but I was not able to invoke a function in the new document's modules even though it was exported by and imported from a previous module. But, if the script was loaded again, then all worked as if a new page was loaded.

I'm not suggesting this is a good practice, but the question was left sort of as if this was all mysterious unintentional side effects rather than having to do with how style sheets and scripts are executed when a document is parsed. It appears to be no different from some very old questions, here, that concerning how to run a script retrieved from an `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
  let
     d = new DOMParser(),
     b = d.parseFromString( rspObj.data, 'text/html' ),
     src = [],
     c;

  if ( (c = document.querySelector("head")).replaceChildren ) {
    // Not supported in olders version of Safari.
    c.replaceChildren( ...b.head.children );
  } else {
    c.parentNode.replaceChild( b.head, c );
  }
  b.querySelectorAll("script").forEach( v => {
     src.push(v.src); // Or it could be textContent.
     v.remove();
  });

  document.documentElement.replaceChild( b.body, document.body );
  src.forEach( v => {
     (c = document.createElement("SCRIPT")).src = v;
     c.type = "module";
     document.body.appendChild(c);
  });
```