# show html page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an entire html page from html to /html, including script tags, css, etc, stored in a database. I am using jquery to get the variable from a php script based on the id of the row in the database from **another website**.
This all works perfectly but the BODY and HEAD tags are removed - the rest of the html is intact. Can anyone shed some light on this?
here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function getListing(postid){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://my-website.com/url.php",
                data: postid,
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("html").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    getListing("postid=6943");
});
</script>
```

and the php is pretty basic:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");?>
<? if($_POST['postid']) {
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
// get html into a variable here *(code romved)*
echo $html; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of AJAX... Why are you replacing the whole HTML content? Why not just replace the bits that need replacing?

Comment: This related question looks like it might be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236360/replace-the-entire-html-node-using-jquery

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to show the whole HTML page, why not access it via an URL?

Comment: thanks Treborbob.. that works. maenu, I want to produce the page on another URL using a script tag only.

Comment: it works in all browsers except IE.. sigh

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `<form>` and post it?  A lot simpler, and it's a pretty basic browser function already:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').append($('<form/>', {
    id: 'newForm',
    action: "http://my-website.com/url.php",
    method: "POST"
  }).append($('<input/>', { name: 'postid' value: '6943' })));
  $('#newForm').submit();
});
```

When you post a form and the server responds with an HTML page, the browser loads it over the old page.