# Stripping head/body tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js, mustache

**When rendering a simple template, with any tag, it renders fine.**

E.g.

```
Mustache.render("<div>{{bd}}</div>", {bd:"DONE"} );
```

renders:

```
<div>DONE</div>
```

**When using any of the 2 tags (`head`,`body`), it looks as if they are stripped for some reason**.

E.g.

```
Mustache.render("<body>{{bd}}</body>", {bd:"DONE"} );
```

renders:

```
DONE
```

---

What's going on? Any ideas how this can be properly handled? *(I mean:* HOW to get the `<body>` tag to render?)

---

**UPDATE :**

Just realized what's going on: the template is being rendered fine. However for some reason, I cannot see the tags...

```
// Previewing this one, the <head>/<body> tags are stripped
$("html").html(Mustache.render(someTemplateWithHeadBodyTags, data));

// Here the tags show up fine, but it's just text
$("html").text(Mustache.render(someTemplateWithHeadBodyTags, data));
```

Re-phrasing the question: How can I set the whole page body WITH the tags included?

---

**UPDATE 2 :**

Thanks to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236360/how-do-i-replace-the-entire-html-node-using-jquery) by @JonBenedicto, this is how I did it:

```
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
newDoc.write(Mustache.render(someTemplateWithHeadBodyTags, data));
newDoc.close();
```