# Capture a click anywhere on the page, even on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This chunk of code

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
});
```

captures a click anywhere on the page.

Unless that click is on a link, in which case the browser seems to follow the link rather than popping up the modal (at least, this is the behavior in Chrome).

How can I capture that the click, even if it's on a link?

One idea: overlaying the page with a fixed-position div that covers everything and captures the click. But maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: You'd prevent the default action of whatever is clicked, but as this is the document, no links will work? Is this really what you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return false;`:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) { 
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
  return false;
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tBT9r/)

For more information read [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11184286/1420197).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) { 
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
  return false; // avoids the propagation and the link default behavior
});
```