# add class when mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a situation here, I need to add some borders to the element that I hover. I'm doing it with Jquery,  I searched for similar questions here but all have a specific selector like `$(".myClass")` or `$("#myId")`. But mine is with `$("*")`. My code is working, but the problem is that if I have an element inside another element both elements has the class that I added. And I only need to add the class to the element I have entered.

This is the HTML, is a basic example because ids an elements may change.

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
        <h2>TESTING MOUSE OVER</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#first{
    background-color: red;

    padding:50px;
}
#second{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;

}
.over{
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

And the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body *").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("over");
    });
    $("body *").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    });
});
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k4y00sa2/
I hope I made myself clear.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching an event handler using `$("body *")` will attach the handler to every single element in the tree, so loses some performance, and won't work for dynamically added elements. Better to attach it once, delegated to the body element only.

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", "*", function(ev) {
  $(ev.target).addClass("over");
  return false;
});
$(document).mouseout("*", function(ev) {
  $(ev.target).removeClass("over");
});
```

```css
#first {
  background-color: #ffffce;
  padding: 50px;
}
#second {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
.over {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <h2>TESTING MOUSE OVER</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/k4y00sa2/3/

```
$("body *").mouseover(function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    $(".over").removeClass("over");
    cur.addClass("over");
    return false;
});
```

I am removing over class wherever over class exists. And putting it to only the child element since that's the order of traversal if you hover over inner elements.

Answer (score 0):

All nodes are handling the event. After one deals with it, you need to stop it from bubbling.
By returning false, the event is not spreaded any more nor the browser will handle it anymore.

```
$("body *").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("over");
    return false;
});
```

[check it](http://jsfiddle.net/k4y00sa2/1/)

[Returning false in events is a shortcut for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11184286/819651):

```
ev.preventDefault();
ev.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for.  It seems like you would just select the actual elements by class or type or something.  But maybe something like this will help.  It wont add the class if the parent of it has it already.  Essentially skipping each other item through the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body *").mouseover(function(){
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("over")){
        $(this).addClass("over");
        }
    });
    $("body *").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    });
});
```

Comment: The Idea is something like yours, but I have tried and for example the red div still with the borders, and if I have 3 elments I have to see 3 black borders when I mouseover each element, but there is one that is not adding the "over" class, I don't know if is the H2 or the second div

Comment: It will add to it if the parent doesn't have it.  So via your HTML it will border the first DIV, skip the second, then border the H2.  Depending on how they are nested it will simply border every other node.

Comment: Also, if you know which elements you want the effect on.  Why not just change the CSS class to be .over:hover  and then add class="over" to each element that you want the effect on.  Then you don't even need javascript.