# Dropdown Menu - Links do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a good working dropdown menu on my website, however, it didn't close when I clicked somewhere else on the page. It took me a while but I got this code written to get rid of this problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".submenus").click(function( ) {
        $(this).toggleClass('tap');       
        return false;
     });

    $(document).click(function( ) {
    $(".submenus").removeClass('tap');
    });
 });
```

Now another new problem occurd. Like I have said, the menu works perfectly, but since I have added this new code, the links within the menu do not open anymore when clicking on them, however, they do open when I right click and then open it in a new window. My assumption is that this new code closes the links before the code gives the website the task to open the link. That way it will try to open something it cant fint. 
That's my assumption, but do not know how I could solve this.

Thanks for your help,
Jan

Comment: `return false;` prevents the redirect. See [return false from jQuery click event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11184286/2294657) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out thanks to the tip I received above,
I needed to replace the "return false" with "event.stopPropagation();"