# Links loaded via ajax won't then load via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating an ajax loading site, new to this and struggling with my links which are loaded into the container via the .load method then don't function the same way when clicked...they instead just load the page as html standard.

If it matters I am using wordpress as a cms and loading the pages from the permalinks.

I'm using something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.ajax').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .content';

        $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {

            $('.content').load(toLoad,'',function() {

                $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 1}, 1000);

            });

        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error near ajax-wrapper.animate

Comment: Thanks, fixed that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is probably event delegation, basically you bind the event to elements that stay available throught the life of the document

```
$(document).on('a.ajax', 'click', function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .content';

    $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {

        $('.content').load(toLoad,'',function() {

            $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 1}, 1000);

        });

    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably only need event.preventDefault(), the event being an argument to the click listener function. Docs: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Yes,  `return false;` will not stop propagation in this case of the `a` tag. [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184276/return-false-from-jquery-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.ajax', function (e){


        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .content';

        $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {

            $('.content').load(toLoad,'',function() {

                $('.ajax-wrapper').animate( {opacity: 1}, 1000);

            });

        });

        return false;


        });
```