# How can I refresh a form page after the form submits to _blank?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, onsubmit

I have an HTML form which targets `_blank`. I would like the page that form is on to reload after submitting.

So here's some sample markup:

```
<form method="POST" action="result.php" target="_blank">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

So when you submit this form it will `POST` to `result.php` in a new window or tab. This leaves the form page as is. I want the form page to reload, or at least reset all fields.

I've tried `<form onsubmit="location.reload()"...` as well as `onsubmit="window.location.reload()"` but nothing changed.

Any suggestions?

(please no jquery)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not sure why `window.location.reload()` doesn't work.  I think it should.  However, this does seem to work:

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

Comment: perfect! not sure why I didn't think of that. I guess I've just been away from JS for too long. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But the time 10 is not that good since sometimes the submit is fast while sometimes slow.

Comment: I agree that the 10 is not so great (what if the server is having a bad day and takes longer than 10 ms to save the changes).  I found this great nugget here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567796/781079 that uses ajax

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, one that you may not want to hear about.

**FIRST:**

In the form init tag, if you set `action=""` then the form will submit to the same page (to itself).

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

This allows you to add server-side code to the top of the page, like this (using PHP, for example):

```
<?php
    If (empty($_POST)===false) {
        //server side scripting to handle the submitted form
    }else{
?>
    //HTML to create/show the page with form for user input
<?php
    //Close the if statement
    }
?>
```

**SECOND:**

Use AJAX (javascript or jQuery) to "submit" the form, and then -- in the AJAX function's callback -- carry on with whatever changes you want to make to the page, including redirecting to a new page.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not produce the desired results for me.

```
Accepted answer:
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

Changing the accepted answer from onsubmit to onclick did fix my issue;

```
Worked for me:
onclick="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 3)"
```

There may be undesirable results, or this may not be preferred but it performs as desired for me.

Comment: It's not reliable to rely on timing. This can randomly fail based on server load, network speed etc.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if a callback is passed to the onsubmit event attribute. For example,

(Traditional anonymous function)

```
onsubmit="function() {location.reload()}"
```

or

(Arrow function)

```
onsubmit="() => location.reload()"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
location.refresh(true);
```

will help

Comment: Thanks. i know this was downvoted. but it worked for me. did precisely what i needed. i.e. Refreshed my partial after i submitted.