# javascript submit form and capture response

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have from which will be submited to iframe:

```
<form id="myform" action="http://example.com/" target="myiframe">
     //some fields
</form>

<iframe name="myiframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Then on some point I submit this form with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();   
</script>
```

How to capture response after .submit()?

I can't use jQuery and Ajax call.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit

Comment: your response should be inside the iframe so just get the contents of it ?!

Comment: I cannot use jQuery and ajax

Answer (score 1):

1. You might run into cross domain issues, since you won't be able to access `http://example.com/` contents with JavaScript, unless your JavaScript is also hosted on `http://example.com/`.
2. If form action leads to the same domain, you can do smth like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ATCJA/):

   **html**

   ```
   <form id="myform" action="http://fiddle.jshell.net/" target="myiframe">
        //some fields
   </form>

   <iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" src=""></iframe>
   ```

   **javascript**

   ```
   var iFrame = document.getElementById("myiframe");
   var form = document.getElementById("myform");

   iFrame.onload = function () {
       /** do smth with your iframe data */
       console.log(iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
   };

   form.submit();
   ```

**Please note** the domain name in jsfiddle code - it points to the same domain, the JS is executed at, to prevent cross-domain access issues.