# setTimeOut function not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time with setTimeOut function .Let me show the code first.

Here is my code :-

```
function submitform(loginUrl, username, password) {
    try {
        loc = new String(window.location);
        document.forms.frm_login.action = junctionUrl;
        document.forms.frm_login.username.value = username;
        document.forms.frm_login.password.value = password;
        document.forms.frm_login.submit();
        setTimeout(gotoHomePage,4000);
    }
    catch (e) {
    alert(e.message +"submit form");
    }

}

    function gotoHomePage()
    {
      alert("test");
      var url = "test.aspx";
      window.location=url;
    }
```

But here the gotoHomePage function is not at all triggered after the specified 
4 seconds.

What i am doing wrong here.Please suggest .

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you place setTimeout(gotoHomePage,4000); before the document.forms.frm_login.submit(); and try ?

Comment: When did the clock start? Is this script running after document ready event or is the clock starting when the page is being parsed?

Comment: I will try that ,but could you please suggest me why to do so,thanks

Comment: @Wayne ;i am calling this from my aspx page ,then this event is been fired

Comment: @AAhad : i tried your suggestion ,but it havent worked

Comment: @VipinNair My connected died 1/2 way through tring to post the comment... or after the submit has already changed the URL. If you are attempting a redirect after posting data its to late. You can instead post the data using ajax or use the php on the server to do the redirect.

Comment: are you calling the `submitform` function from somewhere, or is it just on your page?

Comment: My connection is killing me. You may also be able to submit the form to a target url / an iframe.

Comment: @ps2goat : i am calling it from my aspx code

Comment: After form submit it refreshes the page so yes right you have to use Ajax.. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit

Comment: Okay @AAhad : i will try it out

Comment: @VipinNair - Be careful when using `new String`. `new String` does not return a string, just saying.

Comment: you'll have to show the relevant aspx/html code.  ASP.NET webforms adds its own code for postback, in which case your function would be called, but the form would post back before you'd see anything from your call to `setTimeout`.  JavaScript is asynchronous, so the postback to the server would be initiated before the `setTimeout` is called.

Answer (score 0):

form submission is redirecting to the result page `unload`ing the current page. So, the timer doesn't tick.

Use ajax or set target of the form to iframe. This way, the current page doesn't unload and so timer ticks executing your timeout function.

```
<form target="form_output">
    <!-- other inputs -->
</form>

<iframe name="form_output"></iframe>
```