# JavaScript: How to get http response as a result of click

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, httpresponse

I'm trying to get **response** of **GET request**, that starts after `document.getElementById('btnPdf').click();`

I'm using Selenium **Webdriver** as **JavaScriptExecutor**.

My question is similar to this [How do I capture response of form.submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit) but I don't know exact `url` and would prefer to use pure JS without AJAX (if it's possible).

Comment: That is possible, probably, the question is just a little vague. Please clarify what exactly you want to do. When you say "pure js without ajax" do you specifically mean jQuery.ajax? because "ajax" is a technique.

Comment: That's only because I use JavaScriptExecutor instead of usual browser. I appreciate any help using any technique.

Answer (score -1):

function get

```
Response() {
      var send1='senddata'; // this is a var to send
      var send2='senddata2'; // this is another var to send
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'myGetPageName',true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
              var myResponse = xhr.responseText;
              alert(myResponse);
          }
      };
      xhr.send('myvar1=' + send1 + '&myvar2=' + send2)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how it solves my problem. I don't know url, just click the button and want to catch response

Comment: You can't post or get from a mystery URL. Sound like your using someone else's script and you won't get a response as a var unless they wrote it that way.