# How to read response of POST request sent from an HTML form to Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js

I am making a "create an account" form. After the user submits it, the server makes sure fields are not empty and username is not taken (docs stored in MongoDB). In case of mistake(s), I want to send back as a response the mistake.

HTML below:

```
    <form action="/createaccount" id="myform" method="POST">

    <label>Enter your first name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstname">

    </br><label>Enter your last name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname">

    </br><label for="uname">Enter a username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">

    </br><label for="psw">Enter a password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">

    </br><button type="submit">Create Account</button>
    <div id="error"></div>


</form>
```

Node.js server below:

```
app.post('/createaccount', (req, res) => {
    new_username = req.body.username;
    new_password = req.body.password;
    new_firstname = req.body.firstname;
    new_lastname = req.body.lastname;

    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        db = client.db('entelligence')

        var myobj = {
            firstName: new_firstname,
            lastName: new_lastname,
            username: new_username,
            password: new_password
        };

        var match = false;
        var empty = false;
        var error_string = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            console.log(array[i].username);
            if (array[i].username == new_username) {
                match = true;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            error_string = "Username is  already taken. "
        };
        if (new_firstname == '' || new_lastname == '' || new_username == '' || new_password == '') {
            error_string += "Field(s) cannot be empty";
        }
        console.log(error_string);

        if (error_string == "") {
            db.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document inserted");
            });
            res.redirect('/');
        }

        res.send(error_string);

    })
})
```

When I press on create account, I get "can't set headers after they are sent" error, but I can't find where I sent more than 1 response for 1 request. Also, if I make a mistake (i.e. leave a field blank), I get directed to /createaccount where I get a text with the correct mistake. I don't want to load any page in case of a mistake. I just want an error to show on the page of the form. Anyone has an idea on how to do it?

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/)! Your line break elements have end tags (which are forbidden) but no start tags (which are mandatory)!

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with when the headers on the response are being set on the response. [This answer has some good explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) on why this happens.

This often occurs when you have multiple `res.send`s or `res.redirect`s being called, try and return them to prevent this:

```
app.post('/createaccount', (req, res) => {
    new_username = req.body.username;
    new_password = req.body.password;
    new_firstname = req.body.firstname;
    new_lastname = req.body.lastname;

    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        db = client.db('entelligence')

        var myobj = {
            firstName: new_firstname,
            lastName: new_lastname,
            username: new_username,
            password: new_password
        };

        var match = false;
        var empty = false;
        var error_string = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            console.log(array[i].username);
            if (array[i].username == new_username) {
                match = true;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            error_string = "Username is  already taken. "
        };
        if (new_firstname == '' || new_lastname == '' || new_username == '' || new_password == '') {
            error_string += "Field(s) cannot be empty";
        }
        console.log(error_string);

        if (error_string == "") {
            db.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document inserted");
            });
            return res.redirect('/');
        }

        return res.send(error_string);

    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks that is clear now :) I'm still wondering how to read that response in the html (onsuccess: function() ...) where can I put onsuccess with a POST method in a form?

Comment: It isn't easy to do if you're doing a proper form submit, it can be preferable to send the post request manually and handle it there. This has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit