# how to display a response message on html after post request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i wanted to display a message in html page after submiting the data, wether it is correct or not on the same html page, till now i can only do is show the message on new page.

below is the node code

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.body)
        if(req.body.yourname!='mohit')
          res.send('Content-Type' )
        else  
        res.send('thankyou for submission')
    }catch(error){
        res.send()
    }
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server started to'+port);
})
```

Below is the html code

```
 <div class="container">  
    <form id="contact" action="/login" method="post">
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
      <fieldset>
        <input name="yourName" placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input name="Email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input name="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input name="site" placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="url" tabindex="4">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>

       </form>
```

help would be really appricated?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374644/how-do-i-capture-response-of-form-submit . Though you should prefer fetch() instead of jquery by now.