# How can I get response of form.submit()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-ziparchive

I have to download large archive files on client browser.
To achieve it I called controller method which returned Stream:

Server code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Download(params Guid[] UIds)
{
      if (CampaignId == null)
          throw new ApplicationException(Constants.SESSION_ERROR);
    
      using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866")))
      {
           zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed;
    
           foreach (PPService.FileResult file in GetDocs(CampaignId.Value, UIds))
                        zip.AddEntry(
                            file.FileName,
                            file.Content);
    
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                 zip.Save(memoryStream);
                 return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip");
            }
       }
}
```

Client code:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Download", "Home")';
    var archAction = url;
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "downloadPublicDocs");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", archAction);
    form.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
    form.target = "_self";        
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    
    form.submit();
    
    $("#archLoader").fadeIn(1000);
```

Then I need to catch submit request to show user "Download completed" and do this
`$("#archLoader").fadeOut(1000);`

I had tried to use:

1. form.addEventListener("onload", async (event) => {});
   not working. onload event not fired at all.
2. $.post(form.requestSubmit())
   .done(function (e) { handler here })
   .always(function () {})
   .fail(function () {});

   not working
3. var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", form.requestSubmit());
   xhr.onload = function (event) {
   alert("!!!"); // raw response
   };

   not working. onload event not fired

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {}

   not working. onload event not fired

Is there any solution?
I couldn't use any way except form approach, because I will get an error. But how could I handle response?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't ... form submit loads a new page - as for your attempts number 2 and 3 - `requestSubmit` does not do what you think - and it returns `undefined` - so ... that's enver going to do what you think

Comment: check this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730069/1910035